# How to pass Optional[<type>] as a function parameter with a <type> = default?

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I'm trying to defer a default parameter of the [class](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html) I'm using to its `__init__` (simulated here with a function for simplicity) by passing the None default:

```
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

def f(timeout: int=1):
    pass

@dataclass
class C1():
    timeout: Optional[int]

    def __post_init__(self):
        f(self.timeout)
```

This results in

> Argument of type "int | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "arg" of
> type "int" in function "f"   Type "int | None" cannot be assigned to
> type "int"
>     Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "int"
>
> Argument of type "Unknown | None" cannot be assigned to parameter
> "arg" of type "int" in function "f"   Type "Unknown | None" cannot be
> assigned to type "int"
>     Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "int"

How do I hint or restructure this so that Pylance accepts my optional field to be passed down?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying at all. Especially the first sentence is very confusing and I don't see any connection to the code you showed. Aside from that, the error is very clear. The `C1.timeout` attribute is declared as `int | None`, while the `timeout` parameter of `f` is of type `int`. Therefore passing the former to the latter is not type safe. What about this is unclear to you? Are you _sure_ that by the time `f` is called, the `timeout` attribute will be `int` (not `None`)? If so, just add a type guard with an exception. (e.g. `assert isinstance`)

Comment: What do you want to happen when `C1()` is called, and `timeout` is `None`? Should `f` be called? If so, with what arguments? The `None` in `timeout`, or the `1` `f` defaults to?

Comment: Perhaps `f` is the wrong place to specify a default. Define `f` to *require* an argument of type `int`, and do something like `f(1 if self.timeout is None else self.timeout)` in `__post_init__`. Pylance should be able to apply type narrowing to recognize that `self.timeout` "really" has type `int` if its value is not `None`.

Comment: Even without modifying `f`, you can so something like `f() if self.timeout is None else f(self.timeout)`, using the same type narrowing so that the one-argument call to `f` still type checks.

Comment: I realized that my approach doesn't even work typing notwithstanding. I want to have several `Optional[]` class members and leave the default parameter values up to the constructor (which here would be `f(int)`).

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking how to use function defaults when you pass `None`?
Well there're lots of non-proper, but easy solutions:

---

```
def f(timeout: Optional[int] = None):
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = 1
```

---

```
def __post_init__():
    if self.timeout is not None:
        f(self.timeout)
    else:
        f()
```

---

But I guess you're looking for a more 'proper' solution.
This is more tricky than you might expect and sadly you cannot really have tell the type-checker in a generic way 'use the same signature just that every parameter is Optional'...
You can only mark single parameters as 'Optional' and you can only do that for positional parameters - at least such that type-checkers (aka pyright) understands it.

Here you go - as stated, it's not simple to achieve what you want - but this should work.

```
from typing import *
from dataclasses import dataclass

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")

def use_defaults_for_nones_1(for_func: Callable[[T1], R]) -> Callable[[Optional[T1]], R]:
    return use_defaults_for_nones(for_func) # type: ignore

def use_defaults_for_nones_2(for_func: Callable[[T1, T2], R]) -> Callable[[Optional[T1], Optional[T2]], R]:
    return use_defaults_for_nones(for_func) # type: ignore

def use_defaults_for_nones(for_func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def _wrap(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        new_args = []
        for arg, default in zip(args, for_func.__defaults__):
            if arg is None:
                new_args.append(default)
            else:
                new_args.append(arg)
        
        new_kwargs = {}
        all_default_kwargs = dict(for_func.__kwdefaults__ or {}) # defaults for kw-only parameters
        for name, default in zip(for_func.__code__.co_varnames, for_func.__defaults__):
            all_default_kwargs[name] = default
        for name, arg in kwargs.items():
            if arg is None:
                new_kwargs[name] = all_default_kwargs[name]
            else:
                new_kwargs[name] = arg
        return for_func(*new_args, **new_kwargs) # type: ignore

    return _wrap

def f(timeout: int=1):
    print(timeout)

@dataclass
class C1():
    timeout: Optional[int]

    def __post_init__(self):
        use_defaults_for_nones_1(f)(self.timeout)


C1(timeout=None) # prints 1
```

You may want to check out [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) if you want to implement this in a less 'hacky' way.